# Move folder to parent folder in Azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I have the a container called `container1` inside my storage account.

inside it, I have `Images` directory, which contains multiple directories:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
```

Drawing all together:

```
- container1 (container)
  - Images   (folder)
      - Folder1 (subfolder)
      - Folder2 (subfolder)
      - Folder3 (subfolder)
```

I want move `Images` content to the root level of the container, having this structure at the top level (get rid of `Images` and move its subfolder to its level):

```
- container1
  - Folder1
  - Folder2
  - Folder3
```

I'm trying to use the following command, but it doesn't work:

```sh
az storage blob directory move -c container1 -d . -s Images/* --account-name accountname
```

Comment: What kind of storage account is it - Data Lake Gen 2 or regular?

Answer (score 1):

There's no folders inside a Storage Account container. Which means you have the container name, all the rest is part of the blob name.

Also, there's no way to rename a blob on Azure, you need to re-upload using a different name.

Comment: `you need to re-upload using a different name.` - IMHO, not true. I can copy the blob with a different name and delete the blob to accomplish rename.

Comment: I meant, there's no rename operation. Either re-upload with a different name or copy with a different name and delete the 'original' work in the same way

Comment: Agreed that there's no rename operation. `Either re-upload with a different name or copy with a different name and delete the 'original' work in the same way` - For renaming I would certainly not recommend re-uploading. If you don't have the source blob locally, you would first need to download the blob and then re-upload it. Time consuming, incurs more cost and is error prone.

Comment: I'm using `azcopy` for the upload, not sure how to discard the parent directory since there's no wildcard option if I recall correctly.

Comment: I found a way around this (not programmatically, unfortunately) using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. I'm wondering how they're handling it internally.

Comment: Storage Explorer copies the blobs with a different name + delete to accomplish rename.